# Facebook php sdk - no info being shown

Tags: php, facebook, sdk

I am new to facebook-login system. I have put the following code in http://beta.jokesnfunnypics.com/login . I just copied the code given and just replaced the app id given with mine and the app secret given with mine. But after getting the permission, no info is displayed in the page. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

```
<?php
require 'src/facebook.php';
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'my-app-id-undisclosable',
  'secret' => '-my-app-secret-undisclosable',
));
// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();
if ($user) {
  try {
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}

if ($user) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
}


?>

<!doctype html>
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
  <head>
    <title>php-sdk</title>
    <style>
      body {
        font-family: 'Lucida Grande', Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
      }
      h1 a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #3b5998;
      }
      h1 a:hover {
        text-decoration: underline;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>php-sdk</h1>

    <?php if ($user): ?>
      <a href="<?php echo $logoutUrl; ?>">Logout</a>
    <?php else: ?>
      <div>
        Login using OAuth 2.0 handled by the PHP SDK:
        <a href="<?php echo $loginUrl; ?>">Login with Facebook</a>
      </div>
    <?php endif ?>

    <h3>PHP Session</h3>

    <?php if ($user): ?>
      <h3>You</h3>
      <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/<?php echo $user; ?>/picture">
      <?php echo $user_profile[name]; ?>
    <?php else: ?>
      <strong><em>You are not Connected.</em></strong>
    <?php endif ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: have you downloaded the facebook api? is there any error msg is displaying? You can print the $user value,just to check whether it is getting the user or not (0 or 1).

Comment: yes..I have downloaded it. You can see for anything at http://beta.jokesnfunnypics.com/login

Comment: hmmm..the login is not working.im not able to login there with my fb id

Comment: Can you understand what's the problem?

Comment: have you tried what i've said above? is there any error msg?

Comment: Did you figure this out?  I am running into the same problem.  Everything was working fine the other day. oh well.